# CSVHelper cannot map results

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have a file import that allows the user to import a CSV file that allows the program to add the data to a database. There are multiple mapping files since the CSV files vary in size depending on what data they want to add, this is why there are multiple mapping classes that all inherit from CSVBooking

```
List<string> headers = SplitCSV(textReader.ReadLine()).ToList();
//Called again to reset pos
textReader = new StreamReader(importBookingsFilePath.Text);
var records = new List<CSVBooking>();
using (var reader = new StringReader(textReader.ReadToEnd()))
{
     var parser = new CsvParser(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     if (parser.Read() != null)
         using (var csv = new CsvReader(parser))
         {
             switch (headers.Count)
             {
                  case 77:
                  case 86:
                      csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CSVBookingMapNonPayment>();
                      break;
                  case 78:
                  case 91:
                       csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CSVBookingMapPayment>();
                       break;
                  case 79 when headers.Contains("IP") || headers.Contains("\"IP\""):
                       csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CSVBookingMapNonPaymentExtraIPInfo>();
                       break;
                  case 74:
                       csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CSVBookingMapNonPayment_DaySail>();
                       break;
                  case 87:
                       csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CSVBookingMapNonPayment_Group>();
                       break;
                  case 93:
                       csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CSVBookingMap_Payment_Crew>();
                       break;
                   default:
                       csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
                       csv.Configuration.AutoMap<CSVBooking>();
                       break;
              }
              records = csv.GetRecords<CSVBooking>().ToList();
        }
        else
        {
               MessageBox.Show($"There was an error parsing the file:\n{importBookingsFilePath.Text}", "Parsing error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
               return;
         }
```

The switch statement runs on case 87 with the file I've been provided, `parser.Read()`  returns valid headers and data.

This the mapping file the program currently uses:

```
class CSVBookingMapNonPayment_Group: ClassMap<CSVBooking>
{
     public CSVBookingMap_Payment_Crew()
     {
          Map(m => m.SubmissionDateTime).Index(0);
          Map(m => m.Title).Index(1);
          Map(m => m.Surname).Index(2);
          Map(m => m.Firstname).Index(3);
          Map(m => m.AKA).Index(4);
          ...
    }
}

class CSVBooking
{
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public string SubmissionID { get; set; }
    [Index(0)]
    public string SubmissionDateTime { get; set; }
    [Index(1)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Index(2)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [Index(3)]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I do not like the CsvReader class because I can do same thing in same amount of code without using any special libraries.  There are two many issues that people have with the CsvReader like what you are having.  I need to see sample of CSV file to give a solution.  Been parsing files like this for over 45 years.

Comment: We have a design issue here. Deciding what class to map by checking the number of fields can cause problems in the long run. Besides this, you are passing the base class and it does not have a mapper, hence no records. Should specify a type converter, I guess.

Comment: @jdweng Yeah I've always imported CSV files without using any library but I joined a dev team and they need me to fix an issue with the CSVHelper and for some reason they do not want to switch from that library. For context, I'm importing a csv file that then gets added to a database, [here's a sample file.](https://millenniumltd-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/sebastian_millennium_ltd_uk/ERjCHj6An2VMvjgFK3GRB_wB76OjCYGQlixtxRSUJulgIw?e=qURcUc)

Comment: @OguzOzgul I'm not mapping different classes, they're just different mapping classes that all map to CSVBooking, the users for this program need to import data into a database and the mapping configs allow some variables to not be set as not every field in the database has to be filled. I'm telling it what class to map to not to use the base class as a map.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading a line from the `TextReader` then passing that same `TextReader` into `CsvReader`. This means `CsvReader` will start reading where the `TextReader` is at, which is the second line. It sees the first line read as the header line and matches that up with the registered maps. In your case, that is a data row, and not the header anymore.

My suggestion is to register all the maps at once. Any time a `GetRecord<MyType>` is called, it will use the registered map for that type. You can read several types on a single row if you want, or read a different type every row.

The way to do what you're doing within CsvHelper looks like this.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    s.AppendLine("Id,Name");
    s.AppendLine("1,one");
    s.AppendLine("2,two");
    using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        if (csv.Context.HeaderRecord.Length == 2)
        {
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
        }
        else if (csv.Context.HeaderRecord.Length == 3)
        {
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<BarMap>();
        }

        csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList().Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Guid Property1 { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
}

public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Name);
    }
}

public class BarMap : ClassMap<Bar>
{
    public BarMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Property1);
        Map(m => m.Cost);
        Map(m => m.Date);
    }
}
```

Again, I suggest just registering all maps and not using the `if` statements.

Another reason you'd want to read the first line using CsvHelper is there could be a newline in a field. If that happens, reading a single line through a `TextReader` won't get you the full CSV line.

Comment: I tried creating a new StringReader which does not continue from the same line, but this did not fix the issue. I have different mapping classes because they all link back to the same class CSVBooking, the user will have different sized excel files depending on what data they want to add to the database.
I made a parser for CsvHelper that allows me to read all of the data but it stores the data in a string list / array. 

I made sure that the headers and data was passed to CsvHelper and it is, but it still does not map the records.

Comment: You implemented your own parser? The built in parser returns a `string[]` on `Read`.

Comment: Not my own parser I used the CsvParser and yes it does return a string[]. That's why I said it returns a string / array because you could put ToList at the end to make the data more readable. Still cannot figure out why the CsvHelper does not map all of the properties even though the headers and the data is passed.

Comment: You changed your example to use a parser and reader. You're pulling the first line out with the parser, so the reader knows nothing about your header. You can do this if you really want to, but you'll need to turn the header record off, and use indexes for all the mappings.

Comment: As you can see in the example, I already had index's set up everywhere and it still didn't work. No I do not pull the first line with the parser, I pull the full reader with the parser and then have the CsvHelper use the parser, I did this so I can run .Read() and see if the header results and data load. I created my own mapping CS file and abandoned CSVHelper.